# Email using React Native Android

Tags: android, windows, react-native

I want to do a feedback form in RN android and for that I need 'email' code. How to proceed with this? Do you have any samples? I already tried react-native-mail but it is just invoking 'Send mail' intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would likely need to look at a email service with a API like Mandrill. You could setup a template and pass it the data from the form and email it to whatever email address you would like. Mandrill wouldn't be a requirement as you could accomplish this with any transactional email service. I don't have any code samples to show as there are many possibilities depending on the service used but code samples from the service you go with would probably give a good ideas as to how to do it.

Comment: Thanks @rmevans9. I'll try and let you know.

Comment: Sharing the code sample to help others. https://gist.github.com/MuruganDurai/41087c128cb2dd6ee5a6#file-reactnativesendemailusingmandrill